# How to display icon in php

Tags: php, html

Currently i am displaying filename in front end but actually i want to display download icon  instead of filename.

So how can i replace $filename with some download icon in php.

```html
return $strHref = "<a href ='".$downloaded_filepath."'>" . $fileName . "</a>";
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: Yes,but this is listing page from php so i want to add display some icon instead of filename

Comment: Ok. I have added an answer. If you have questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Custom image**

```
return $strHref = "<a href ='".$downloaded_filepath."'><img src='imgpath'></a>";
```

**In bootstrap**

```
return $strHref = "<a href ='".$downloaded_filepath."'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For an **icon** you can use something like this:

```
return $strHref = "<a href ='".$downloaded_filepath."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>";
```

For these kind of icons you can use bootstrap (or something else.. what ever you like).

---

If you wish to use an **image** instead of icon you can do something like this:

```
return $strHref = "<a href ='".$downloaded_filepath."'><img src='path_to_image'></a>";
```

---

**Documentation:**

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/ // All available icons
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ // How to install/use bootstrap
- https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_images.asp // image